# Reference error window not defined error in Web3

Tags: javascript, next.js, window, undefined, web3js

Here is my code:

```
import Web3 from './web3';

if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    try {
        // Request account access if needed
        ethereum.enable();
    } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
    }
} else if (window.web3) {
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    console.error('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
}

export default window.web3;
```

I am getting the error as:

> Server Error Reference error Window not defined

Getting error at line:

```
window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
```

Comment: are you sure you always operate in browser environment, not Node for example? In other words, make a check if window is defined before referring to its props `if(typeof window !== 'undefined') { /* your code */ }

Comment: Yes @mtx s right, in node you will need a web3 provider such as infura.